# SQL: find all items on left side where right side items all have specific field value

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table `job` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   Status
-----------
1    NEW
2    NEW
```

There is a table `item` that contains data as shown below:

```
Id   Status   JobId
---------------------
1    NEW        1
2    PROCESSED  1
3    NEW        1
4    PROCESSED  2
5    PROCESSED  2
```

I want to run a query, that will return all Jobs whose "children" all have a status of X

Pseudo-SQL:
`SELECT * FROM Job WHERE status = 'NEW' AND Items for Job WHERE all items status = PROCESSED`

That should return

```
Id   Status
-----------
2    NEW
```

Because all of Job 2 items have `status = PROCESSED`.
Job 1 does not appear because it has items with the unwanted status `NEW`

Comment: FYI, you mean "Pseudo-SQL" I think. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from job where Id not in (SELECT JobId from item where Status <> 'PROCESSED');
```

This will return all from job where id is not in result of all jobids which have status different from 'PROCESSED'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT j.* FROM Job j
WHERE not exists (select 1 from item i where i.JobId = j.id and i.Status != 'PROCESSED')
  and exists (select 1 from item i where i.JobId = j.id and i.Status = 'PROCESSED')
  and j.status = 'NEW';
```

Or

```
SELECT j.* FROM Job j
WHERE j.id in 
    (select jobId from ( 
        select jobId, count(distinct status) n_all, 
        count(distinct case when status = 'PROCESSED' 
                       then status else null 
                       end) n_processed
        from item group by jobId
        ) t
     where n_all = n_processed
    )
and j.status = 'NEW';
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d04abf/8)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE job
    (`Id` int, `Status` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO job
    (`Id`, `Status`)
VALUES
    (1, 'NEW'),
    (2, 'NEW')
;

CREATE TABLE item
    (`Id` int, `Status` varchar(9), `JobId` int)
;

INSERT INTO item
    (`Id`, `Status`, `JobId`)
VALUES
    (1, 'NEW', 1),
    (2, 'PROCESSED', 1),
    (3, 'NEW', 1),
    (4, 'PROCESSED', 2),
    (5, 'PROCESSED', 2)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM job
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
       FROM item
       WHERE job.Id = item.JobId AND item.Status <> 'PROCESSED')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d04abf/8/0)**:

```
| ID | STATUS |
|----|--------|
|  2 |    NEW |
```